# prevent bootstrap menu to be opened on specific class or element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu

I am using [dgoguerra's bootstrap-menu](https://github.com/dgoguerra/bootstrap-menu). It works great except I need to prevent bootstrap menu to be opened when I right click on specific class or on specific child element.

Please see the demo.
https://jsfiddle.net/8k0zn6ws/2/

I can prevent bootstrap menu to be opened on 1st and 3rd row but I would like to prevent the menu to be opened if class `label-warning` is clicked. Is it possible to use `preventDefault()` if specific child element or  specific class ( `label-warning`  ) is found in the selector.

I tried 4 - 5 context menus. This was the one that worked stable in my table.

Comment: Changing id to class in  <tr class="demo4TableRow" data-row-id="2"> does not bring up the context menu

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am trying to prevent the menu from initializing  on right click for the child element. changing id to class doesn't effect the child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to select expected elements. For example:

```
var menu = new BootstrapMenu('.label-warning', {
  fetchElementData: function($rowElem) {
    var rowId = $rowElem.data('rowId');
    return demo4Rows[rowId];
  },
...
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Please see the updated jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8k0zn6ws/4/ it didn't work.

Comment: It's just my example, to give you an idea. If you want more details, take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/strv6kyj/

Comment: you have given the same class to tr element and span element in this case I am not sure how it worked but when I glve same class to my tr element and my child elements ( div,ul, button ) it doesn't work. Context menu still opens when I right click to the child elements. Desperately need this.

Comment: The idea is when you create `new BootstrapMenu('.label-warning')` you need to pass the class name into its contructor

Comment: I gave the class label-warning to the child elements and it didn't work. please see updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/strv6kyj/3/ isn't there another solution?